# Acessar variável javascript em laço com model

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Estou criando um projeto Asp.Net MVC e encontrei um problema na View.
Veja o código:

```
<script>
var data = [];

for (var i = 0; i < '@(Model.Count())'; i++) {
    data[i] = {
        "source": '@(Model.ElementAtOrDefault(0).Source)',
        "percentage": '@(Model.ElementAtOrDefault(0).Percentage)'
    };
}
</script>
```

Bem, o que eu preciso é simples! Ao invés de passar um índice fixo (no caso 0), preciso passar o valor de `i`, mas o mesmo foi declarado em javascript e não consigo acessa-lo dentro da expressão em que obtenho o valor da model.

Comment: Um `"source": '@(Model.ElementAtOrDefault('+i.toString()+').Source)'` não resolveu?

Comment: Opa meu brother, infelizmente eu já havia tentado, mas não da certo, pois quando o parenteses depois do arroba é aberto, ele enxerga o _'+i.toString()+'_ como uma string literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Senhores, infelizmente nenhuma das respostas funcionou de primeira, mas ajudaram e muito a chegar na solução!

Acredito que o problema era basicamente algum tipo de incompatibilidade entre o tipo de variável array do razor com o javascript, então tive que passar os dados manualmente.

O código deverá ser assim:

```
<script>
var indexJS = 0;
var data = [];
@{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        @:(data[indexJS] = { "source" : '@Model.ElementAtOrDefault(i).Source', "percentage": '@Model.ElementAtOrDefault(i).Percentage' });
        @:(indexJS++);
    }
}
</script>
```

Bem, acontece que só consigo controlar o `index` da `model` usando `razor`, então uso a variável `i` do laço `for` que criei dentro do razor `@{}` para controlar os índices, e lá dentro do laço consigo fazer acesso a variável `data` criada em javascript usando `@:` e controlando o índice de tal array com uma variável em javascript `indexJS`.

Espero que isso ajude também outra pessoa no futuro. E muito obrigado a toda a ajuda!

Answer (score 5):

Isso não pode ser feito.

A expressão `@(Model.ElementAtOrDefault(0).Source)` tem que ser avaliada do lado do servidor, *antes* do html ser enviado para o browser e, portanto, *antes* do javascript ser executado.

Como o valor de `i` é dinâmico e só vai ser conhecido quando o javascript for executado no browser, é impossível usar a variavel `i` na expressão.

A solução é converter todos os elementos do model para dois arrays em javascript *fora* do loop usando por exemplo `Model.Select(x => x.Source)` e `Model.Select(x => x.Percentage)`  (isso pode ser avaliado do lado do servidor), e depois usar os arrays javascript dentro do loop.

---

**Edit**

Baseado [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23781320/857807), julgo que a sintaxe seja a seguinte:

```
var elems = [];

@foreach (var elem in Model)
{
    @:elems.push(
              new {
                   source = @elem.Source
                   percentage = @elem.Percentage
              });
}
```

Comment: Agora sim! Ficou bem claro, você teria algum código de exemplo para isso?
Pois a minha _model_ é do tipo _IEnumerable<T>_ e estou tendo dificuldades em colocar tudo em um array.

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues Na verdade, tens que usar dois arrays. Editei a resposta, espero que ajude! :)

Comment: Cara, você manda muito!Mas não consegui fazer funcionar... :( Veja: `var modelSource = new Array();
    modelSource = @Model.Select(x => x.Source);`

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues Hmm tenho pouca experiencia com a sintaxe do Razor, mas experimenta este post: [Razor MVC Populating Javascript array with Model Array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23781034/857807)

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues Baseado nesse exemplo, actualizei a resposta com a sintaxe que eu *acho* ser correcta.

Comment: cara, faz muita lógica o que você fez, mas não está pegando os dados. Estou dando uma analisada, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Tente utilizar o laço utilizando a sintaxe `razor` e depois atribuir o valor de um `array` gerado para a variável `javascript`.

Algo assim:

```
@{
   var vetor = new object[Model.Count()];
}

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    vetor[i] = new {
                 source = Model.ElementAtOrDefault(i).Source,
                 percentage = Model.ElementAtOrDefault(i).Percentage
               };
}
```

e depois no `javascript` é só atribuir o `array` para a variável.

```
<script>
    var data = @vetor;
</script>
```

Comment: Top de linha a sua lógica, mas infelizmente ocorre um erro na hora da criação da variável vetor. Invalid expression term 'object'

Comment: Alterei a resposta. Faltou um `new` antes de `objet[Model.Count()]`. tenta ai

Comment: cara, faz muita lógica o que você fez, mas não está pegando os dados. Estou dando uma analisada, muito obrigado.

Comment: O problema só está na hora de atribuir o `array` do `razor` no `array` do `javascript`, simplesmente não funciona. Mas toda a sua sintaxe `razor` está funcionando perfeitamente! Parece apenas haver algum tipo de incompatibilidade...

Answer (score 1):

Eu resolvi com a ajuda de outro post !!

Para um Modelo qualquer no seu projeto, como por exemplo

```
@model IEnumerable<ProjetoNamespace.Models.SeuModelo>
```

Para acessar uma lista desse tipo deve-se usar :

```
<script>
   var minhaLista = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
   for(var i = 0; i < minhaLista.length; i++){
       var elementoLista = minhaLista[i];
       //acesse os atributos a partir do elemento !
       //elementoLista.<atributo>
   }
</script>
```

É isso moçada, espero ajudar alguém !